# Menu a la izquierda PDF a la derecha Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, pdf, bootstrap, jmenubar

Buen dia.
Intento acomodar en toda una columna izquierda el menu  de botones, y en el apartado derecho muestre el visor de PDF al dar clic los botones.
No logro hacer que se acomode todo el menu izquierdo, me queda asi como en la imagen...[image: imagen de como queda]

y lo que busco es que quede asi....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si me pudieran ayudar a acomodarlo, ya intente de varias maneras. Gracias
El codigo es

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-3 col-lg-2 sidenav textarbol" >
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
     
  
    </ul>
  </div>
    </div>
       </div>
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-3 col-lg-2 sidenav" >
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
           </ul>
  </div>
    </div>
      </div>
<!--CONTENIDO DERECHO -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-10">
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-12" align="center">
    
 <object data="aa.pdf" type="text/html"  style="width:80%;height:100vh;">
   </object>
      </div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifique algunas cosas de tu código para que se adapte a lo que necesitabas. adjunto el código

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Object</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col">
                     <div class="dropdown">
                        <button
                           class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                           type="button"
                           data-toggle="dropdown"
                        >
                           Tutorials <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                           <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col">
                     <div class="dropdown">
                        <button
                           class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
                           type="button"
                           data-toggle="dropdown"
                        >
                           Tutorials <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                           <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-10" align="center">
               <object
                  data="cleancode.pdf"
                  type="text/html"
                  style="width: 80%; height: 100vh;"
               >
               </object>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias men, me sirvió el codigo que pasaste, de ahi partí en continuar el resto. !!